# beep sound in python audiolab

Tags: python, audio, numpy

How do i generate a gentle "beep" sound in python [audiolab](http://www.ar.media.kyoto-u.ac.jp/members/david/softwares/audiolab/sphinx/index.html), without the use of external .wav files? I found the following example to generate random noise:

```
play(0.05 * np.random.randn(2, 48000))
```

Unfortunately i do not have enough knowledge of audio representations to create a beep (of a certain frequency) and i have no idea where to find some understandable documentation.

Any help on this would really be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be precise:

```
import audiolab
import scipy
x = scipy.cos((2*scipy.pi*f/fs)*scipy.arange(fs*T))
audiolab.play(x, fs)
```

where `f` is the frequency of the tone in Hertz, `fs` is the sampling rate, and `T` is the length of the tone in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
play(0.05 * np.array([math.cos(x/40) for x in range(10000)]))
```

generates a pretty nice tone, in wich the values:

- 0.05 defines the volume;
- 40 the frequency;
- 10000 the length of the tone.

Ciau!